# Why is my class variable not being initialised properly?

Tags: c++

```
class Client {
public:
    const int NO_ROOM = 0;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in* servaddr;
    int roomid;
    char* nick;
    Client(int fd, sockaddr_in* sa, int r=0, char* n=""): sockfd(fd), servaddr(sa), roomid(r), nick("") {
        cout << "set id: " << this->roomid << endl;
    }
};
```

This is my class. When I instantiate it like so:

```
Client c = Client(sockfd, &servaddr, c.NO_ROOM);
```

I get the following output:

```
set id: -1
```

Which really makes no sense to me.

Comment: what is `c.NO_ROOM` ? Please [mcve]

Comment: oh sorry. It is complete ;) You are using the object before it is alive.

Comment: `char* n=""` requires a deprecated conversion. You may be using an old compiler. String literals cannot be assigned to non-const `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `c.NO_ROOM` as the third parameter, which at that time is uninitialized and contains random information. The further code then uses this value to initialize the member variable.

You can declare `NO_ROOM` as `static` or even better `constexpr`, this way the compiler will enforce it's value as a constant, instead of it getting initialized for each instance when it is created.

Comment: Is there a way to pass in a `NO_ROOM` variable without making it global?

Comment: I tried replacing `const` with `static` or `constexpr`, but it wouldn't compile. In the case of `constexpr`, I get: `error: non-static data member ‘NO_ROOM’ declared ‘constexpr’`

Comment: @doctopus [Constant static members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members)